# Why is getattr() throwing an exception when an attribute doesn't exist?

Tags: python, django, django-models, getattr

This one has me baffled. Consider the following Django models - representing zookeepers and the cages at the zoo that they are responsible for cleaning:

```
class Zookeeper(moodels.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Cage(models.Model):
    zookeeper = models.ForeignKey(Zookeeper)
```

Now suppose I want to connect a receiver to the `Cage`'s `post_init` signal:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_init, sender=Cage)
def on_cage_init(instance, **kwargs):
    print instance.zookeeper
```

As expected, this raises an exception since the `Cage` has not yet been assigned to a `Zookeeper`. Consider the following modification to the body of the receiver:

```
print getattr(instance, 'zookeeper', 'No Zookeeper')
```

One would expect this to print "No Zookeeper" since one has not been assigned to the instance. Instead, an exception is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../zoo/models.py", line 185, in on_cage_init
    print getattr(instance, 'zookeeper', 'No Zookeeper')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 324, in __get__
    "%s has no %s." % (self.field.model.__name__, self.field.name))
DoesNotExist: Cage has no zookeeper.
```

Why is it raising an exception? Isn't `getattr()` supposed to return the provided default value if the attribute does not exist? I can prove that the attribute does not exist with:

```
print hasattr(instance, 'zookeeper')
```

...which prints `False`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@metatoaster's explanation is really good and this is basically what is happening. See `__get__` magic method defined [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.5/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L324).

As a solution, I would apply ["Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission"](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper) principle. Try getting the attribute and catch the specific exception:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

try:
    print instance.zookeeper
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    print "No zookeeper"
```

Comment: You could also avoid importing `ObjectDoesNotExist` by instead catching `Zookeeper.DoesNotExist`.

Answer (score 9):

Most likely that class has `__getattribute__` defined.  See this example:

```
>>> class O(object):
...     def __getattribute__(self, name):
...         raise Exception("can't get attribute")
...
>>> o = O()
>>> getattr(o, 'test', 'nothing')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __getattribute__
Exception: can't get attribute
```

Note how `getattr` essentially calls `o.__getattribute__` internally, and if that raises a generic exception, it will just fail with that exception.

However, if it was properly define to raise `AttributeError`, `getattr` will catch that properly.

```
>>> class O(object):
...     def __getattribute__(self, name):
...         raise AttributeError("can't get attribute")
...
>>> o = O()
>>> getattr(o, 'test', 'nothing')
'nothing'
```

So this could be considered as a bug in the definition of the `DoesNotExist` exception where it does not correctly inherit from `AttributeError` as it should have.

A more complete example to demonstrate all of the above:

```
>>> class O(object):
...     def __getattribute__(self, name):
...         if name == 'test':
...             return 'good value'
...         elif name == 'bad':
...             raise Exception("don't raise this")
...         else:
...             raise DoesNotExist()
...
>>> class DoesNotExist(AttributeError):
...     pass
...
>>> o = O()
>>> getattr(o, 'test', 'nothing')
'good value'
>>> getattr(o, 'something', 'nothing')
'nothing'
>>> getattr(o, 'bad', 'nothing')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __getattribute__
Exception: don't raise this
```

Of course, all that above doesn't exactly help you in working around that bug.  Rather than waiting for that bug to be resolved, just implement your `getattr` that traps that exception (or any other exceptions that you might be expecting).  Something like this might work:

```
def safe_getattr(obj, name, default):
    try:
        return getattr(obj, name, default)
    except Exception:  # or your specific exceptions
        return default
```

Comment: +1 good explanation ±0 horrible naming (`o`, `O`, `O0`, `oO`, `Oo`) ;)

Comment: @msw the `O` and `C` keys are literally next to each other, I swear!